# Customer address does not save if redirect from observer in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have added an custom observer and added custom logic to redirect after saving the address. redirection works fine but address does not save. I also tried to print the new address in observer.It display the new address but after redirection previous address is displaying.
Redirection code

```
$this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($r_url)->sendResponse();
exit();
```

Event xml code

```
<event name="customer_address_save_after">
    <observer name="test_observer_name" instance="Namespane\ModuleName\Observer\RedirectafterAddressUpdate" />
</event>
```

Comment: Can you please add whole method code and which event you are using ?

Comment: I have updated question,Please have a look

Comment: you have not updated your full PHP code